# Refreshing page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have created a small fiddle that consist of 2 pages consisting of Home page and a Team 1 page.

When you click on navigation menu on side you can click on team 1 button that takes you to team 1 page.

However if you are already on team1 page and you click on team 1 button how do you make it load the page like earlier when you were on home page.The problem is when your on team1 page and if you click on team1 button nothing seems to happen. how do you get it to refresh or reload the page?

I tried to use the following with no luck.

```
 $( '#items').click(function() {
          location.reload(true);
 })
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f6TQw/13/)

Comment: Well it looks like `#item` is not a button but the wrapper around a couple buttons. Wouldn't you want to mess directly with the button?

Comment: How exactly? because it won't work even if i do it with the button directly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > The problem is when your on team1 page and if you click on team1 button nothing seems to happen. how do you get it to refresh or reload the page?

jqMobile allows you to load page specific script; define click actions for each button in that script:

```
    $("#revertButton").click(function() {

         // don't make any changes, just go back

         $.mobile.changePage($("#page2"), { transition: 'slidedown' });

     });
```